# Required property conditional display on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I need to display the required property(asterix) depending on the value of radio button selected. How can this be achieved using javascript?

```
<p class="signatoryLabelAdditional" ng-class="{required:!currentQuoteQto.preferredBillingCity}"
   translate>qrDetail.billingCity</p> <input type="text" class="signatoryInput" ng-model="currentQuoteQto.preferredBillingCity"
                                             ng-change="modifyBillingInformation()"
                                             maxlength="50"
                                             name="billingCity"
                                             ng-disabled="currentQuoteApproved() && currentQuoteQto.approvalLevel == null ||  billingCountryDisabled"
                                             required>
<p ng-show="additionalInformationForm.billingCity.$invalid && submitClicked" class="formError" style="clear: both; margin-left: 205px" translate>form.mandatory</p>
```

Comment: pretty simple using `ng-if` or `ng-show`

Answer (score 0):

Angular supports using conditional ng-required where you pass parameter that resolves to true or false:

```
<p class="signatoryLabelAdditional" ng-class="{required:!currentQuoteQto.preferredBillingCity}"
   translate>qrDetail.billingCity</p> <input type="text" class="signatoryInput" ng-model="currentQuoteQto.preferredBillingCity"
                                             ng-change="modifyBillingInformation()"
                                             maxlength="50"
                                             name="billingCity"
                                             ng-disabled="currentQuoteApproved() && currentQuoteQto.approvalLevel == null ||  billingCountryDisabled"
                                             ng-required="your_radio_button_value_here">
<p ng-show="additionalInformationForm.billingCity.$invalid && submitClicked" class="formError" style="clear: both; margin-left: 205px" translate>form.mandatory</p>
```

See the documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired